# Passing PHP array into Javascript through JSON to update Google Chart

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have three PHP arrays that I've encoded with json... extra PHP code has been omitted because the arrays work properly.... Additionally, the HTML  tags that call the google chart have been omitted for sake of brevity...

```
<?php
$encoded_line_volume = json_encode($LineVol) . "\n";
$encoded_loan_volume = json_encode($LoanVol) . "\n";
$encoded_cluster_name = json_encode($ClusterLine) . "\n";
?>
```

I would like to access these three arrays in Javascript to update my Google Chart dynamically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["columnchart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var linevol = new Array;  // This would be the first array passed from PHP
var loanvol = new Array;  // This would be the second array passed from PHP
var clusters = new Array; // This would be the third array passed from PHP

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Cluster');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Loans');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Lines');

/* create for loops to add as many columns as necessary */

var len = jsonarray.length;

    data.addRows(len);

for(i=0; i<len; i++) {

data.setValue(i, 0, ' '+clusters[i]+'');     /* x-axis */
data.setValue(i, 1, linevol[i]);   /* Y-axis category #1*/
data.setValue(i, 2, loanvol[i]);   /* Y-axis category #2*/
}
/*********************************end of loops***************************************/
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, is3D: true, title: 'Prospect Population', legend: 'right'});
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'd love to help out, but your code is incomplete and lacks formatting ;)

Comment: Justin... just reformatted it... should be complete now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want them to become Javascript variables. When your php executes, it creates code your web browser then interprets. So you want to define javascript strings using php. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var encoded_line_volume = <?php echo json_encode($LineVol) ?>;
    var encoded_loan_volume = <?php echo json_encode($LoanVol) ?>;
    var encoded_cluster_name = <?php echo json_encode($ClusterLine) ?>;
</script>
```

Then those variables are accessible to subsequent javascript.

Comment: thanks, ken... will I need to parse each variable to create corresponding javascript arrays?

Comment: Parse in Javascript? No, not if the array is a normal array in PHP. Json encodes the variable so that it interprets directly as a javascript variable -- that's why there are no quotes around them.

If you view the page source, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

This is how can you generate data dynamically from PHP, generate a JSON formatted output properly and read it from JavaScript (JQuery required) and load it to Google Visulization (Charts) API.

PHP (Server) Side:

```
function returnData() {
    $data = Array ();
    $data [] = Array ("Name", "Value");
    $data [] = Array ("Apple", 5);
    $data [] = Array ("Banana", 3);

    header('content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

Javascript (Client) Side:

```
var jsonData = null;

var jsonDataResult = $.ajax({
    url: dataURL,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: (
        function(data) {
            jsonData = data;
        })
});

var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
```

Comment: This works I integrated your codes with other codes and it worked 4 me thanks a lot Man

Answer (score 0):

This is  one of the best examples I did which can help you : its tested and working nicely : Create two pages one called index.php and another one called get_json.php :
 This is not exactly the codes you posted but exactly the same idea and it answers the quetion.

```
the codes for index.php 

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>King Musa Graph</title>
        <!-- Load jQuery -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <!-- Load Google JSAPI -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "get_json.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;

                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);

                var options = {
                    title: 'King Musa'
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
                            document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html> 

codes for get_json.php
<?php

    $data = Array ();
    $data [] = Array ("Name", "Value");
    $data [] = Array ("PHP", 78);

    $data [] = Array ("JAVA", 1000);
  $data [] = Array ("HTML", 129);


    $table = json_encode($data);
   // header('content-type: application/json'); 

    echo $table ; // this line is important it should be not disabled 

?>
```